# NGINX - INSANE I/O on Reload/Reboot

Tags: nginx

My NGINX server is doing like 30Gb/s+ read and writes on reload which freezes the whole box.

Any idea why this is happening? Been running NGINX for years without this problem before.

Maybe just traffic growth? I'm doubtful... The IO is insane.

Here is a DSTAT example of when I ran a service nginx reload

```
`
 18  82   0   0   0|2680k   35M|  75M   61M| 736k 2396k|  54k   17k
  4  80   1  15   0| 198M 3782M| 118M   88M|  12M 1870M| 119k   43k
  6  15  13  66   0|4948k 7216k| 777k  227k| 416k   68k| 542   452
  5  11   7  77   0|  25M 1410M|  27M   13M|1868k  698M|  36k   15k
  7  22  10  61   0|  95M 1644M|  37M   31M|4152k  823M|  53k   26k
  5  24   7  65   0| 158M 2408M|  46M   49M|  21M 1191M|  84k   50k
  6  25   7  63   0| 128M 1535M|  38M   40M|7936k  762M|  65k   39k
  5  13   7  76   0|  77M 1737M|  39M   33M|5684k  862M|  50k   24k
  3  69   7  20   0| 440M 4029M|  71M   59M|  81M 1929M| 178k   73k missed 2 ticks
  7  31   8  54   0| 216M  448M|  22M   18M|  93M  288M| 279k   56k
  5  15   1  79   0| 745M 4283M|  56M   56M| 473M 2064M| 241k  215k
  8  19   1  72   0| 594M  336M|5447k 5138k| 112M  163M|  31k   33k
 12   6   3  79   0|1182M  922M|  22M   16M| 573M  457M| 117k  161k
  6  19   1  74   0|1092M 3766M|  33M   19M| 502M 1891M| 271k  184k
  1   3   1  95   0| 168M  389M|  15M   12M|  58M  180M| 100k   52k missed 3 ticks
```

1   1   1  96   0|1044k 2484k| 490k  185k| 572k 1424k|1533   581

`

Comment: Please show the output of `iotop -a` when the issue happens

Comment: Reload happens fast - appears that for 30 seconds after a reload something happens that is crazy IO

Do we know what NGINX does when reloaded? What could this IO be?

Comment: Why don't you strace nginx to see what is it doing? `systemctl stop nginx; strace nginx -g "daemon off;"`

Comment: @NginxGoodButSometimesAnnoying so run `iostat -a` in a terminal, reload/restart nginx on another terminal and, during reload, check which processes are hammering the disks.

Comment: Solved: WEIRD BUG. Will document for you guys for potential future case. Old expired cached files in the a parent directory of the cache directory somehow was causing this.

Seems to be a bug with NGINX, because after deleting them all fine now. Strange.